# Another condition for determining recurrent & transient states of Markov chain (Norris exercise 1.5.3)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

**Overview :**
Below problem reinforces Norris theorem 1.5.3 for time homogeneous  discrete time markov chain  $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ with state space $I$

> The following dichotomy holds: 
>  (i) if
> $P(T_i= \inf\{n\ge 1 : X_n = i \} <\infty | X_0 = i \in I) = P_i(T_i <\infty)=1$ , then $i$ is recurrent and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{ii}^{(n)} = \infty $
>
>   (ii) if
> $P(T_i= \inf\{n\ge 1 : X_n = i \} <\infty | X_0 = i \in I) = P_i(T_i  <\infty) < 1$ , then $i$ is transient and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{ii}^{(n)} < \infty $  
> In particular, every state is either transient or recurrent .

where $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{ii}^{(n)} = E[\text{number of visits to state i}]$ , by providing an extra "iff" relationship :
$P_i(T_i <\infty) = 1 \iff \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{ii}^{(n)} = \infty  $ .

I have trouble deducing one intermediate result of the problem.

Norris called this problem "First passage decomposition" , although I don't understand why .

**Problem :**
Given the identity
$$
p_{ij}^{(n)} = \sum_{k=1}^n f_{ij}^{(k)} p_{jj}^{(n-k)} \quad n\ge 1
$$
Deduce that
$$
P_{ij}(s) = \delta_{ij} + F_{ij}(s) P_{jj}(s) \tag{1}
$$
Hence show that $P_i(T_i< \infty) = 1$ iff
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{ii}^{(n)} = \infty 
$$

**Notations** :

- The time homogeneous discrete time markov chain here is $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$
- $p_{ij}^{(n)} = P(X_n=j|X_0=i) = P_i(X_n=j) \qquad  \text{(n-step transition probability , deduced from p.25)}$
- $T_i = \inf\{n\ge 1 : X_n = i \}  \qquad  \text{(first passage time , from p.24)} $
- $f_{ij}^{(n)} = P_i(T_j=n)$
- $P_{ij}(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{ij}^{(n)}s^n 
  \qquad  \text{(s is some real constant I guess)}$
- $F_{ij}(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_{ij}^{(n)}s^n$
- $\delta_{ij}$ is Kronecker delta i.e $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ , $0$ otherwise

**Attempt :** I first tried to justify the given identity . Starting from RHS , for $n \ge 1$ ,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n f_{ij}^{(k)} p_{jj}^{(n-k)} = \sum_{k=1}^n P_i(T_j = k) p_{jj}^{(n-k)} 
$$
by strong markov property , condition on $T_j = k$ , then $(X_n)_{  n > T_j}$ is independent of $(X_n)_{ 0\le n \le T_j}$ , so
$$
= \sum_{k=1}^n P_i(T_j = k) P_i(X_n = j | T_j = k ) 
$$
$$
= P_i(X_n = j ) = p_{ij}^{(n)}
$$
I have no idea how to deduce (1) . But assuming (1) holds , then setting $i=j , s = 1$ ,
$$
P_{ii}(1) = 1 + F_{ii}(1)P_{ii}(1)
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{ii}^{(n)} = 1 \Big/ \left(1 - \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_{ii}^{(n)} \right)
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{ii}^{(n)} = 1 / \left(1 - P_i(T_i<\infty) \right)
$$
now it's obvious that that  $P_i(T_i<\infty) = 1 \iff \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{ii}^{(n)} = \infty$

**Question :** How to deduce (1) ? It's not very obvious to me .